# How to use an MH-Z14a CO2 sensor?

Tags: arduino, sensors

I have to use an MH-Z14a sensor, I've tried a lot of solutions but none of them work. I ended up with wiring the PWM to the digital 2 of my Arduino Mega2560, the V+ on 5V or 3.3V (non of them give something working) and V- to GND, and I tried this code:

```
// set interrupt pin numbers to recive outhput signal:
const int sensorPin = 2; // Pin 2 as the sensor pin
long laag = 0;
long hoog = 0;
long laagTijd = 0;
long hoogTijd = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // set sensor pin as an input
    pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT);
    // Read starting value for millis…
    while(digitalRead(sensorPin) == LOW) {;}
    hoog = millis();
}

void loop(){
    // Check for high and low timing – low time * 2 = PPM
    while(digitalRead(sensorPin) == HIGH) {;}
    laag = millis();
    hoogTijd = laag - hoog;
    while(digitalRead(sensorPin) == LOW) {;}
    hoog = millis();
    laagTijd = hoog - laag;
    // Validity check high+low = 1004 (small margin or error allowed -> 990)
    if(laagTijd + hoogTijd > 990)
    {
        Serial.print("H: ");
        Serial.println(hoogTijd,DEC);
        Serial.print("L: ");
        Serial.println(laagTijd,DEC);
        Serial.print("CO2 – ");
        Serial.print(laagTijd * 2,DEC);
        Serial.println(" ppm");
    } else {
        // Output in case of invalid check: value instead of 1004 ms
        Serial.print("– CK:");
        Serial.println(laagTijd+hoogTijd, DEC);
    }
    delay(4000);
}
```

I had this output:

(the normal value of CO2 outside is around 400ppm)

```
H: 4008
    L: 10
    CO2 – 20 ppm
    H: 4008
    L: 10
    CO2 – 20 ppm
    H: 4007
    L: 11
    CO2 – 22 ppm
    H: 4006
    L: 13
    CO2 – 26 ppm
```

I also tried code from these websites, but nothing works:

- https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/mh-z-co2-sensors/
- https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/mh-z14-a-library
- https://innovatorsguru.com/mh-z14a-arduino-code/
- http://www.doctormonk.com/2018/03/review-and-test-of-mh-z14a-ndir-co2.html

Here his the datasheet of the component:
https://www.winsen-sensor.com/d/files/MH-Z14A.pdf

Can someone help me to use this sensor please?

Comment: the code from their site is written for a Nano. Try a Mega 2560 PWM pin from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping2560

Comment: I tried the pins 2; 4; 10 and 44 but it was all the same

Comment: Did you read the datasheet or understand the datasheet? Under the section "PCM Output", there is a formula on how to calculate the value, your code didn't do that but merely get the timing info. If I read your code correctly, you only did `laagTijd * 2` and since `laagTijd` is always 10, so it will be "all the same" as 20.

Answer (score 0):

Install the MH-Z library open the example.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <MHZ.h>

// pin for pwm reading
#define CO2_IN 10

MHZ co2(CO2_IN, MHZ19B);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(CO2_IN, INPUT);
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("MHZ 19B");

  // enable debug to get addition information
  // co2.setDebug(true);

  if (co2.isPreHeating()) {
    Serial.print("Preheating");
    while (co2.isPreHeating()) {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(5000);
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("\n----- Time from start: ");
  Serial.print(millis() / 1000);
  Serial.println(" s");

  int ppm_pwm = co2.readCO2PWM();
  Serial.print(", PPMpwm: ");
  Serial.print(ppm_pwm);

  int temperature = co2.getLastTemperature();
  Serial.print(", Temperature: ");

  if (temperature > 0) {
    Serial.println(temperature);
  } else {
    Serial.println("n/a");
  }

  Serial.println("\n------------------------------");
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).